# Get Filepath from uploaded file on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I just configured my application to use Google Cloud Storage for storing user uploads. So far I was able to retrieve the file path of an uploaded by doing so:

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, file.key)
```

However, on Google Cloud Storage this gives me the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `path_for' for #<ActiveStorage::Service::GCSService:...>)
```

How can I retrieve the filepath here?

Comment: This is probably because they don't want you to work on the underlying OS layer? So my guess is that you can't and if you do find a way it will be a hack that will be closed at some point in the future.

Comment: @ekampp You are probably right

Answer (score 1):

You can use `url_for_direct_upload(key, expires_in:, checksum:, **)` or `url(key, expires_in:, filename:, content_type:, disposition:)` to get the GCS urls.

[Reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Service/GCSService.html)